# asp.net Ajax timer control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have a page with a timer control. when the page is loaded, it fires a function. 
my issue is that the title of the page appears initially, but after the timer control function finished, the string in the title disappears.
I commented everything out of the timer function and the title in the string still appears.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET AJAX and programatically define the page title (as opposed to statically having it defined in your .aspx page), then you must re-define it again in your partial page update. It's just the way asp.net ajax works.

Comment: i am redefining programatically it in a the timer handler and pageload, yet it still does not set the title.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like asp.net ajax does not like the asp:Literal control in the title bar. I removed the literal control from the title bar and replaced it with 
<% Response.Write(szTitle); %> 
that worked for me!